# Using AJAX to pull information from XML and post into HTML

Tags: html, css, xml

I have an assignment that asks for certain information to be pulled from the XML using AJAX. So far I have my HTML, information.xml and below is my code.  I also have

```
<body onload="loadinfo();">
```

in the body of the HTML.

My question is how would I pull information from XML to load into the HTML?

```
    function loadinfo() {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= readinfo()
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "information.xml", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }


    function readinfo() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.informationXML;

            var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TechnicalSupport")
            root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            grabinfo = root.getElementsByTagName("TechnicalSupport")



        }
    }
```

This is my XML:

```
<TechnicalSupport> 
  <info online-phone="1-800-588-7885" 
        online-email="TechnicalSupport@html.edu"
        campus-phone="1-800-588-7886"
        campus-email="CampusSupport@html.edu"/>  
</TechnicalSupport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to do too much of your homework for you, but I would look into the following pages for how to turn the xml that you are loading with ajax into variables that you can read with Javascript. Then you can assign them to be the values of html elements on your page.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp